# How to automatically refresh date in Google spreadsheet published to the web?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Spreadsheets to maintain a register of all students in my school and track their monthly payments. Each student has a separate Google spreadsheet maintained and in the spreadsheet I am also calculating their age using their date of birth and `now()` function. The data is published on the school website.

However, I find that the `now()` function does not automatically update and save the current date unless some changes are made to the spreadsheet. This means that the data on the web is not refreshed until the spreadsheet has been edited.

How can I make the date to update automatically in the spreadsheet, so that the data published on the web always shows the current date without manually editing and saving the Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the interval for recalculation of the spreadsheet in the *Spreadsheet settings* which you can find in the *File* menu.

There you can set it to recalculate on change and/or every minute or hour.

Through this, functions like `Now()` should be updated automatically in the interval you set.